# Adding user controls with code nuggets not code behind

Tags: asp.net

My project currently adds user controls to a web form via code behind e.g.

```
For Each p In userlist
            Dim uc1 As New TimeSelector

            panel.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<asp:panel1 runat=" & "server" & ">"))
            panel.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(p.ToString))
            panel.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<asp:Updatepanel1 runat=" & "server" & ">"))
            uc1 = DirectCast(Page.LoadControl("~/UserControls/StaffScheduling/TimeSelector.ascx"), UserControl)
            uc1.ID = "UC" & j
            panel.Controls.Add(uc1)
            panel.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("</asp:Updatepanel1>"))
            panel.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("</asp:panel1>"))
            panel.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<p></p>"))
            j += 1
        Next
```

Is there a better way to add user controls to a web form other than code behind? Am I taking the best approach?

Regards

Comment: Why not just try putting the equivalent of that code in your designer (.aspx file) and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

If there is maximum no of User Controls that you need to add, why not add then in the markup?

Why you ask?

1. People often run into problems with there usercontrols not showing.
2. Usercontrols events not getting fired, because the usercontrols do not exist in the markup instead are dynamically generated.
3. There is no difference in the speed(page-size). You can toggle there visibility according to your needs.
4. Much cleaner, elegant solution.

Frankly, you should use this approach to save yourself from numerous hassles arising from your approach.

Comment: It is a varied number of controls depending on user list back via entity framework query. My issue is each control had 14 comboboxes in each when selected does and insert or update to the database. I am struggling to complete the query as the controls can not see the user list because its outside the main aspx file.

Comment: Why not have a maximum no. of controls and a next button to show the next set of results? I did it with my own project.

Comment: Each user control combobox is a componet one wijmo:C1ComboBox

Comment: there is no issue with the number of controls they display just fine. I can not get the database update/insert working cause the user control code behind can not see markup on the main aspx page they are loaded into.

Comment: Well that's a totally different question, SO has many questions of this type, search SO and you will definitely find the solution.

Comment: SO brings back so many different issues any chance of narrowing it down~?